# Center DIV with fixed (bottom) position

Tags: css

I cant seem to be able to center #testmenu no matter what... I've tried dozens of combinations in CSS but without luck. Please take a minute to have a look and save my hair from being completely pulled out.

```
#abc {
    position:absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    text-align:center; /* IE 5.x centering */
}

#testmenu {
    line-height:2em;
    width:960px;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#00F;
  background:#C00;
    margin:0 auto;
}

<div id="abc">
    <div id="testmenu">
        This should remain 'fixed' bottom center.
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a simple jsfiddle of what I'm after: http://jsfiddle.net/mXTmF and also working demo of the page: http://ht-webcreations.com/vildiridis/index.php

Comment: that is peculiar, I'm having a look at the moment but finding the root problem is difficult, very strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can't apply auto margins to a fixed element. To allow for varying menu widths, I'd do this:

```
#abc {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px; /* forces #testmenu to the bottom */
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#testmenu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden; /* prevents extra space underneath from 33px-high menu items */
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are quite straightforward, since you're using a fixed width for the menu. Add the following CSS on your `#testmenu`:

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
```

You can see a working demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/mXTmF/1/

Comment: Possibly because it requires an explicit margin value. It doesn't allow for varying element width.

Comment: @isherwood Except that this is almost 2 years old now (and there are better ways to achieve this), you're right, it doesn't allow for varying widths. However, the original question **specifically** deals with a **fixed width** element, as the answer quite clearly states...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style='border:1px solid; width:960px; height:200px; position:absolute; left:50%; bottom: 100px; margin-left:-480px;'>hallo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in Css

```
#testmenu {
width: 960px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: 100px;
margin-left:-480px;
}
```

Comment: Try to provide an answer that relates to the question. Your question has the correct method, but it might be difficult for the OP to tell how he can integrate it into his specific problem.

Comment: @BenM: cant understand your critics sry, thats a one click copy and paste example.